# how to give more then one having clause

Tags: mysql, sql

i have different value in statuss column like received,bounced,cleared and i want to get total number of rows on every statuss

```
select roll_no as roll,sum(pdc.amount) as amount,count(amount) as given,
       stu_profile.name,f_name,scholarship,class_id,batch_id,statuss
from stu_profile
    left join pdc on pdc.roll = stu_profile.roll_no
where 1 and class_id != ''
group by roll
```

Comment: Use analytical function to achieve this

Comment: Just add statuss column to the group by clause

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select roll_no as roll,sum(pdc.amount) as amount,count(amount) as given,
   stu_profile.name,f_name,scholarship,class_id,batch_id,statuss
from stu_profile
left join pdc on pdc.roll = stu_profile.roll_no
where 1 and class_id != ''
group by roll
having amount > 0
   and count(amount) = 4
```

You can append multiple having conditions by using *and*

Comment: Using `&& 
   and ` ?? it a bit to much

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for noticing that..it was a typo on my part. I have edited the answer